# Compare two MySQL databases, on command-line, with a free tool

Tags: mysql, sql, diff

I would like to generate diff-like SQL files to compare the DATA and the STRUCTURE of two MySQL databases.

These resulting files would be executed as SQL queries, on command-line.

There is various old threads related on SO, and on various forums, but they deal with non-free tool with user interface (not command-line tools).

Also, the database should not be synced directly, but only by executing the resulting diff SQL script.

Comment: Thanks for Galz and ADW for your help. Even if I am not using the solution you've propposed, I considered it anyway, so it was useful. I am diging into liquibase atm. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases which is a related issue (but broader. my issue was especially about MySQL, command line, and free tool). Check http://forum.liquibase.org/#Topic/49382000000251069 as well for an example, and see if it is a feasible solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following will have a go at showing you the differences (the first part of your question) but the output won't really be useable as patch files.

To compare two tables:

```
 mysql -u whatever -e "describe table" database1 > file1.txt
 mysql -u whatever -e "describe table" database2 > file2.txt
 diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

To compare data:

```
 mysql -u whatever -e "select * from table" database1 > file1.txt
 mysql -u whatever -e "select * from table" database2 > file2.txt
 diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

To compare databases:

```
 mysqldump --extended-insert=FALSE -u whatever database1 > file1.txt
 mysqldump --extended-insert=FALSE -u whatever database2 > file2.txt
 diff file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: `diff` is part of mysql?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the open-source Percona Toolkit ---specifically, the [pt-table-sync](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-table-sync.html) utility.  It uses checksums on indexes and other strategies to diff tables **fast**.  Its primary purpose is syncing replicas, but with a little extra work, it's a great diff tool.  See [my full answer about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839333/diff-2-large-database-tables/8462251).

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that comparison of the structure is a different beast.  I do this with a stored procedure that you can call from the command line, but it may not be what you're looking for.

Here's a snippet from a shell-script wrapper that I wrote for showing schema diffs:

```
mysql ${MYSQL_CNF_OPTION} -u ${DB_USER} \
-e "USE sys; CALL compareDBs('${DBDIFF_LOCAL_DB1}','${DBDIFF_LOCAL_DB2}');"
```

It calls the `compareDBs` stored procedure, which I got from [the Artful Software query archive page](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#624).

Comment: Thanks for sharing Royce! Didn't know [Artful Software query archive page](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php)!

Answer (score 2):

Tools for schema compare are more common. There are some perl packages for this which can easily be run from command line. I also found one for data diff (which is quite a complex problem!), but it's kind of old and I am not sure how good it is.

Schema compare:
http://adamspiers.org/computing/mysqldiff/

Data Compare:
http://rossbeyer.net/software/mysql_coldiff/